# Meaning of statement in GRASS r.horizon manual

Tags: grass-gis, dem, geotiff-tiff, web-mercator

I have a question about this statement in the [`r.horizon`](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.horizon.html) manual:

> "If your projection is based on distance (easting and northing), these
> too must be in meters. The buffer parameters must be in the same units
> as the raster coordinates."

I have a DEM TIF based on a Web Mercator projection for an area of interest at latitude -37.841477522046524 (scale factor ~1.26). The pixels in the TIF have a real world resolution of 0.15m.

Do I need to preprocess the TIF in anyway to satisfy the *"these too must be in metres"* requirement? Do I need to rescale to a pixel size of 1m? Do I need to obtain transform the TIF into a projection where the scale factor is 1?

Comment: Eastings and Northings are similar to lat and lon except E/N is usually used for projected coordinate systems, witch includes EPSG:3857 https://epsg.io/3857 as the units are metres so therefore your buffer should be in metres, if your CRS had units of feet the buffer would be in feet and if your CRS is geographic, assumedly, your units should be in decimals of degrees though I'd argue transforming to a projected CRS would be better to buffer in.

Comment: Ok, so to confirm, because I am using EPSG:3857, we can consider the projection to be in metres, even though, in practice easting and northings are not metres but metres scaled by the local scale factor. In other words, the guidance was I need metres based Eastings and Northings not feet-based.  I am also assuming there is no need for me to down sample from 0.15m to 1m resolution.

Comment: I'd say that is the case, not having used r.horizon (yet), from the way it reads to me they're trying to say that r.horizon only works in projected coordinate reference systems and the buffer is expressed in the same units as the coordinate reference system. I would be very surprised if a tool required resampling to 1m to work, usually it's the other way around as bigger cell sizes are required to speed up processing.

Comment: I took liberty to change the manual page URL to https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/r.horizon.html which is way better to read (which is from 2020 while your Debian manual link pointed to an outdated version from 2013...).